# How to center list items

Tags: html, css, html-lists, listitem

I just don't get it right. How do I center *list items* inside the `ul`?

```css
body {margin: 0}

ul {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 11px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a><li>
  <li><a href="#">Over mij</a><li>
  <li><a href="#">PO's</a><li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a><li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What exacty do you mean with center in ul? Why not just apply "text-align: center;" to ul?

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought I tried it, but it appears I didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox***:

```css
body {margin: 0}

ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  justify-content: center; /* centers them horizontally */
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 11px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a><li>
  <li><a href="#">Over mij</a><li>
  <li><a href="#">PO's</a><li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a><li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add

```
 text-align:center;
```

in the ul styling. You will achieve.

```
ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align:center; 
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  display: flex; /* added */
  justify-content: center; /* added */
}
```

Then play with the margin-right for the anchors as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `text-align:center` to `ul`

```css
ul {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 11px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Over mij</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">PO's</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```